# Laravel Environment Configuration with Heroku

Tags: heroku, laravel-4

I am writing my code on Nitrous.IO using Laravel I configured my start.php to the following

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('harrenhal-php-95199'),
  'staging' => array('*.herokuapp.com'),

));
```

I tried this format I also tried the hostname itself both seems not to working. is there a specific practice to do so?

Once I run hostname on the shell in heroku I get this result "9e7831e0-284c-48b8-88a4-3afbbbac0b35" which changes over time.

the problem php don't detect herokuapp.com so the staging environment doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

From the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration)

> If you need more flexible environment detection, you may pass a
>   Closure to the detectEnvironment method, allowing you to implement
>   environment detection however you wish

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return $_SERVER['MY_LARAVEL_ENV'];
});
```